# Are there infinite cardinals $\kappa$, $\lambda$ with $\kappa^\lambda = \kappa$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Going through an exam question for revision.

I need to prove the following:

> Are there infinite cardinals $\kappa$, $\lambda$ with $\kappa^\lambda = \kappa$?

I really am not sure, though intuition says no.

I am then asked to state and prove Cantor's Theorem, i.e. there is no surjection from a set to its power set. This is also simple to prove.

The final part of the question asks

> Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal number. Prove $2^\kappa ≠ \aleph_0$

This I am also basically clueless for. Perhaps I can show that for any subset of the naturals, its power set has size either less than or greater than $\aleph_0$, depending on whether or not the subset is finite? But I am not sure if this would even work, let alone constitute a proof.

Any hints anyone can provide would be helpful, since it would help me learn better if I can come across the solutions to these by myself!

Thanks

Comment: If $2^{\lambda}=\kappa$ the $\kappa^{\lambda}=2^{\lambda\times\lambda}=2^{\lambda}$ since $\lambda^2=\lambda$ when $\lambda$ is an infinite cardinal.

Comment: If $\kappa$ is finite then so is $2^\kappa$. If $\kappa$ is infinite, then $\kappa \geq \aleph_0$, and so $2^\kappa \geq 2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_0$. In either case, $2^\kappa \neq \aleph_0$.

Comment: While this first part of the question has already been answered, here is another answer: take $\kappa_1$, $\lambda$ to be any infinite cardinals. Now take $\kappa=\kappa_1^\lambda$. Note that if $\lambda\geq{\kappa}_1$ then $\kappa=2^\lambda$. If $\kappa_1<\lambda$, then a "precise expression" for $\kappa$, say one that doesn't involve $\kappa_1$ is much trickier and might not be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Try $\kappa=2^{\aleph_0}$ and $\lambda=\aleph_0$. 
We need to biject sequences of 0-1 sequences with 0-1 sequences. But sequences of sequences are just a 2-dimensional array, and this can be treated wit Cantor's zigzag enumeration.

---

If $\kappa$ is finite, then $2^\kappa$ is finite. If $\kappa\ge\aleph_0$, then $2^\kappa\ge 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: It's probably best to avoid unnecessary use of the axiom of choice in basic questions like this. The alternatives "$\kappa$ is finite" and "$\kappa\ge\aleph_0$" are not exhaustive in the absence of choice. However, if $2^\kappa\le\aleph_0$ then $\kappa\le\aleph_0$ so in this case everything is fine, either $\kappa$ is finite or $\kappa=\aleph_0.$

Comment: In fact, if $2^\kappa\le\aleph_0$ then, by Cantor's theorem that sets are strictly smaller than their power sets, $\kappa <\aleph_0$.